# What is mechanism of Whatsapp application's Contacts syncing?

Tags: android, performance, mobile

I have a requirement like, I can be able to find the people who are using a particular app from my contacts. It is much similar like Whatsapp contacts syncing.

Whatsapp contacts is so fast & very accurate. What is the logic for it?

Comment: I also what to know how whats app contact sync works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of their exact logic, but a way that I have seen it done before is as follows...

1. Access the phone's contacts (duh)
2. Get the contact that you want to add as a "friend" in your app.
3. Cross reference that contact's phone number with the user information that you have stored in your application's database
4. If that phone number exists in your database of users, then you've got a match and you can process things however you'd like from there.

That's one way of doing it, but I don't know if that's exactly how WhatsApp does it. Hope this helps!